# NSKeyedUnArchiver back to your original custom NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an object i have made that is storing all information from twitter however i need to give it a load state so it needs to be saved to memory.

This is the code i have done so far below

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    rssParser = [[RssParser alloc] loadXMLbyURL:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/2smssupport.xml"];

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rssParser];
    [prefs setObject:data forKey:@"Tweets"];
    [prefs synchronize];

    NSData *olddata = [prefs dataForKey:@"Tweets"];
```

I need to get the olddata back to its original form  as an 'RssParser'

If anyone can help out it would be ace! its been ravaging my brain the last day or so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does RssParser implement NSCoding? If so, you just have to do

```
NSData *olddata = [prefs dataForKey:@"Tweets"];
RssParser *oldRssParser = (RssParser *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:olddata];
```

Otherwise you should read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1

Comment: Thanks great! yes it implements the coding. Can you maybe explain to me why the first parenthesis is used?

Comment: well, basically NSKeyedUnarchiver only knows that it will return some kind of object, not what kind of object exactly. With (RssParser *) you basically tell the compiler that the returned object will be a RssParser object, i.e. you cast that object into a RssParser object